# Mac Mini M2 - no image with ATEN 4 Port USB 3.0 4K DisplayPort KVMP Switch

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, displayport, kvm

I have a new Mac Mini M2 connected with a USB-C / Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable with the ATEN 4 Port USB 3.0 4K DisplayPort KVMP Switch with the model number CS1924 for Video.

I also have a USB3 Cable from an USB-A Port connected to the ATEN KVMP switch.

When I connect the USB-C / Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable directly with the monitor, I get a perfectly fine 4K image. But when I add the switch in the chain (DP to DP cable from switch to monitor) the monitor stays in power safe.

But it works, when I start with a direct connection and later disconnect and reconnect with the KVM switch in-between.

This is the USB3.1 Information:

```
USB 3.1 Bus:

  Host Controller Driver:   AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIASMedia3142
  PCI Device ID:    0x2142 
  PCI Revision ID:  0x0000 
  PCI Vendor ID:    0x1b21 

4-Port USB 2.0 Hub:

  Product ID:   0x5411
  Vendor ID:    0x0557  (ATEN International Co. Ltd.)
  Version:  1.19
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: Generic
  Location ID:  0x02300000 / 2
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    0
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

Hub:

  Product ID:   0x8021
  Vendor ID:    0x0557  (ATEN International Co. Ltd.)
  Version:  1.00
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/s
  Location ID:  0x02330000 / 4
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

Apple Keyboard:

  Product ID:   0x0250
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  0.74
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID:  0x02331000 / 5
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    20
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

SpaceMouse Compact:

  Product ID:   0xc635
  Vendor ID:    0x256f
  Version:  4.37
  Speed:    Up to 1.5 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: 3Dconnexion
  Location ID:  0x02310000 / 9
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

4-Port USB 3.0 Hub:

  Product ID:   0x2410
  Vendor ID:    0x0557  (ATEN International Co. Ltd.)
  Version:  1.19
  Speed:    Up to 5 Gb/s
  Manufacturer: Generic
  Location ID:  0x02100000 / 1
  Current Available (mA):   900
  Current Required (mA):    0
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

This is what I get for the monitor:

```
  Chipset Model:    Apple M2
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  Total Number of Cores:    10
  Vendor:   Apple (0x106b)
  Metal Support:    Metal 3
  Displays:
LEN P27u-10:
  Resolution:   3840x2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 - Ultra High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    1920 x 1080 @ 30.00Hz
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
```

Comment: When you say “stays in power safe” do you mean that when you “select the Mac on the KVM, the display stays blank”?

Comment: I assume it’s the [CS1924](https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/kvm/desktop-kvm-switches/cs1924/) (including model numbers helps greatly).  If you leave the KVM plugged into the Mac but plug the display in directly bypassing the KVM, does the switching work as it should?

Comment: @Allan Sorry for the late reply, got side tracked. Yes, it's exactly the liked model CS1924. And yes, I have the monitor now directly connected with a USB-C/TB (?) to DP cable, which works fine. I still can switch the USB connections between connected computers.

Comment: You confirmed what I suspected as happening.  Certain KVMs (to save money) don’t keep the video signaling “high” to each of the workstations on the switch.  Apple has “tighter tolerances” where if this signal doesn’t exist, it will keep the display in sleep mode; windows doesn’t have this problem (as much).  You’ll have to see if ATEN has a firmware update or something to address this because if you remove the KVM display connection, everything works as it should.  You’ve narrowed it down to the KVM

Comment: @Allan Thanks, you are absolutely right. I upgraded the firmware now to the last one, but sadly this had been the one installed already. Hence, as expected no behavior change. Have to contact the support on this issue.

Comment: Just to give an update, I didn't get it to work. Sometimes the monitor shows up, most of the times it stays black or sometimes grey, which is even more weird.
I think I am giving up on trying to get this up an working. Too much time wasted already. Asked support for firmware update, but we know hot likely this is on such an old device...