# HDMI KVM which is working with a Mac Mini M2 and 4k monitors - also sleep and reboot

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport, reboot

After I have used a Aten CS1924 KVM for DP for years between my PC and MBP without any issue, the introduction of a Mac Mini M2 renders my setup unusable.

[On reboot, the Mini doesn't detect the monitor which stays black](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458763/mac-mini-m2-no-image-with-aten-4-port-usb-3-0-4k-displayport-kvmp-switch). No problems, when I disconnect and reconnect the DP cable.

Anyway, after several tries to fix this together with their support I am looking for a working cheap alternative solution.

Which are tested with Mac Mini M2 (including reboot :) ) working HDMI KVM switches?
Thanks